# Postgresql - подстановка переменной с NULL или UUID значением в динамический запрос

Tags: postgresql

Мне необходимо подставить значение переменной `parent_id` в другой запрос. Переменная может получить значение или `NULL` или тип uuid, например `14cecd67-5681-e29d-df1e-f02305fa6d63`. Затем мне необходимо эту переменную воткнуть в запрос, где `WHERE id = 1 AND pid (IS | =) parent_id`

Проблема, собственно, заключена в скобках: я не знаю заранее, какое значение будет у переменной и не могу сформировать заранее синтаксис запроса, т.е. указать проверку на NULL как `IS` в случае, если переменная будет иметь значение `NULL`, либо же поставить знак `=` если будет иметь значение `14cecd67-5681-e29d-df1e-f02305fa6d63`

подскажите, что делать?

Comment: часто пишут что то вроде `( (pid is null and parent_id is null) OR (pid=parent_id) )`

Comment: @Mike спасибо Вам огромное, Ваши советы всегда отлично работоспособны!